# .net remote attribute, How call after page load?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a question from title,
How to call remote attribute after page load?
now behaviour is that this will be activate when user click input.

Thank you for advice!
Best Regards

Comment: Why you need to call remote attribute after page load?Remote attribute must have an input,if you want to validate an input when page load,you can try to use  $("xxxform").validate(),and set the validation rules by yourself on client-side.

Comment: That's good idea!!! Thank You!

I have idea that that when user display register page he will see error`s password  requireds.
And if he complete any, it will be removed.